# Shared Memory Access Across threads

Tags: c, multithreading, shared-memory

Does shared memory needs synchronization when used in multiple threads. Following is the scenario.

1. Shared Memory Created with type Int Array (in Process Pa).
2. Each thread of Pa has an index to this array and will update array[index] 
   based on some conditions.
3. Do we need Mutex to Synchronize the Int Array Access ?
4. Assuming one more process (Pb) tries to access this Int Array. Do I need 
   mutex (for thread) and Semaphores for process sync.

Let me know comments on same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the array contains pure value types and each thread is operating on a disjoint subset of the array - this is to say that ***each thread has a mutually exclusive set of indices it will be reading/writing to or from*** - then no, you do not need any sort of synchronization.

The array itself is just a block of memory.  What is important is that no two threads try to read or write to the same memory location unprotected - they can happily read and write to interleaved or neighbouring or any other disjoint locations just fine since they won't be stepping on each others toes, so to speak.

If, however, several threads need to read or write to the same indices in the array then you absolutely need to protect those reads and writes with some type of synchronization.  For example, say you have :

```
int ia[10];
```

and two threads.  If you can guarantee (by whatever means) that thread #1 will only access `ia[0..4]` and thread#2 will only access `ia[5..9]` then you're good.  If they both want to read or write wherever, though, you need something to guard those accesses.

Comment: Depends on what OP means by shared memory. True Posix shared memory has all it's reads and writes atomic.

Comment: @SergeyA Surely that's an implementation detail - I don't think C guarantees this generally, no?  Or am I missing something?